# Parsing specific text from cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am having in a `google spreadsheet` multiple cells the following text(only the Language changes):

`Lorem ipsum dolor. sit.com<br><br>Languages: English to Dutch<br/><br/>`

I would only like to display `English to Dutch` in a separate cell.

I tried this: `=REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"<br>(.*?)</br>")`

However, I do not come very far with this solution, because I am getting `#N/A`. Any suggestion what I could do?

I really appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try

```
=regexextract(D2, ":\s(.*?)<")
```